# How to change alignment of Highchart tooltip?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to show some information in Farsi language on highchart tooltip. It works ok but the text align is not right.

As Persian language is a rtl language, I need to change text alignment so it starts from right. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with right to left direction. so I think your document's direction is set to `RTL` either in `html` tag with `dir="rtl"` attribute or in your stylesheet file with some selector like `*{direction:rtl;}` so that everything in your document gonna be right to left. to fix the chart alignment just add the following rule in your stylesheet:

```
#container {
    direction:ltr !important;
}
```

this will reset the direction of the chart to `ltr`, so that It will not be messy. but still it's text-alignment is to left.

Answer (score 5):

dont forget use:(useHTML: true,)

```
tooltip: {
useHTML: true,
 formatter: function() {
 return '<div lang="fa" dir="rtl"> ' +
 this.x + ' : ' + this.y +
 '</div>';
  }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you can do something like this:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return '<div lang="fa" dir="rtl">دستشویی/داروخانه) کجاست؟ : ' +
               this.x + ' : ' + this.y +
               '</div>';
    }
}
```

Is that Farsi? I just googled and found it somewhere.

Some refs:

- [HTML Language Code Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp)
- [Right-To-Left Text in Markup Languages](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html)

Comment: Yeah this is Farsi. I tried it but it diden't work. I even changed style of tooltip in Highchart source code but also it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use some tricks for Farsi language that can be found at this Farsi website http://www.barnamenevis.org